# Is it possible to use the python3 bindings for VirtualBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualbox

I am trying to use the python 3 bindings to VirtualBox but there appears to be broken dependencies. It seems odd to me that this hasn't been fixed over the ~4 years that people have been having this issue. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. It's been known to happen.

I have installed the virtualbox host modules, sdk, and extensions through my OS's pacakage manager. Then, through pip:

```
pip install pyvbox
```

The imports work:

```
from virtualbox import VirtualBox, Session, Manager, WebServiceManager
```

But then any attempt to instantiate anything results in an exception complaining about a missing `vboxapi`.

```
box = VirtualBox()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualbox/library_ext/vbox.py", line 22, in __init__
    manager = virtualbox.Manager()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualbox/__init__.py", line 130, in __init__
    with import_vboxapi() as vboxapi:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualbox/__init__.py", line 45, in import_vboxapi
    import vboxapi
  File "/home/$USER/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3_155965261_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.7.0.201704111357/pysrc/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vboxapi'
```

There is a `vboxapi` on PyPi, but it won't install as there is no code associated with it, nor any useful information on the PyPi page:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vboxapi

Here are a couple links to the valiant efforts of braver souls than I. It is not immediately clear to me which is the correct solution or if either are still relevant, given that they are from 3 and 4 years ago, respectively.

https://github.com/GreatFruitOmsk/vboxapi-py3

https://github.com/jbuergel/vboxapi-py3

Also from 3 years ago, word of a vboxapi.diff and intergration into vboxapi:

https://www.virtualbox.org/pipermail/vbox-dev/2014-April/012231.html

Comment: You could try raising an issue on [the Github page](https://github.com/mjdorma/pyvbox), as it looks like there is activity there.  There is an old issue similar to yours but the only advice was to install the VirtualBox SDK.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ok thanks I'll do that!

Comment: @BrenBarn I read that advice too and went to install it only to find it already installed.

Comment: Could you try my method, for me it is ok now  (Ubuntu 18.04 / Python 3.6 / VirtualBox 6.0)

Answer (score 16):

I'm the current maintainer of the `pyvbox` package.
The VirtualBox SDK already supports Python 3, I use Python 3.5 to develop the library. I recommend uninstalling and reinstalling the latest version of the SDK (which at the time of writing this is 5.1.22).

You can find the SDK on the [VirtualBox downloads page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Unzip the archive and run the `vboxapisetup.py` file using your system Python with the following command:

`python vboxapisetup.py install`

You don't need to install this in any virtualenv, as `pyvbox` will search your system libraries in addition to virtualenv installations for better ease of use.

If you have problems using the `pyvbox` package after running these steps, please open an issue and include as much information as possible including the steps you took, OS, where your system Python is located, which version of VirtualBox & SDK you're using, and I'll help you as best I can.

Comment: Upvoted. Not sure I understand this: "as pyvbox will search your system libraries in addition to virtualenv installations for better ease of use". I thought the entire idea behind virtualenv was not to do anything outside of the virtualenv... But maybe I'm mistaken, in which case I welcome an explanation.

Comment: We basically have to play around the VirtualBox SDK which installs itself within system Python. You can technically install it in a virtualenv but I'd doubt that most of our users want to find their `vboxapisetup.py` file every time they create a new virtualenv so we make our library search system libraries as well for our API bindings.

Comment: I see... this virtualenv stuff smells more and more by the day. I'd run this all in a container... Oh wait... :-)

Comment: Would this work with the [portable version](http://www.vbox.me/archive/)? Not having much success so far.

Comment: I haven't tested with the portable version. If you have some time to spare I'd love it if you filed an issue on the GitHub repository with all the information you have and what you've tried and either I or someone else can take a look at it.

Comment: I have a use case where I'd really love to be able to run this in a virtualenv. Is there anything special I have to do to get that working?

Comment: With the latest release of pyvbox you shouldn't have to do anything special. (We search a lot of places for all installed packages). If you do run into any trouble you can open an issue on our GitHub and I'll get to it.

Comment: The final issue is not on your side (pyvbox)... For me it was due to both ; (1) geting vboxapi inside the python3 dist-package with VirtualBox Sdk installer is tricky  (2) Most of virtualbox installation does not have the python3.6 binding module (VBoxPython3_6m.so) present in virtualbox install dir (/usr/lib/virtualbox)

Comment: I looked at 2.0.0 there is still some python2 left overs like instanceof basestring in process.write. Why not use byte array?!!

Comment: Then do not forget to export the env variable to be able to install the SDK: export VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/lib/virtualbox;sudo -E python3 vboxapisetup.py install

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, it is possible, very tricky to setup but it work fine for me now (Ubuntu 18.04 / python3.6 / virtualbox 6.0) .

---

The error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vboxapi'
```

mean that `python3` does not find `vboxapi` module, now there is two methods to "force-install" the `vboxapi` package to `python3`:

---

**First Method** [easy]: Assuming `pyvbox` is already installed and work fine with python2.7, in that case you can simply copy the package from python2.7 dist-packages to python3 dist-package with:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vboxapi /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

---

**Second method** [more tricky]: Go to [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), then download the last [Software Developer Kit (SDK)](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.4/VirtualBoxSDK-6.0.4-128413.zip), actually the 6.0.4

Unzip the archive and run the `vboxapisetup.py` file using Python3 with the following command:

```
sudo python3 vboxapisetup.py install
```

You will get this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vboxapisetup.py", line 90, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "vboxapisetup.py", line 63, in main
    raise Exception("No VBOX_INSTALL_PATH defined, exiting")
Exception: No VBOX_INSTALL_PATH defined, exiting
```

You may directly edit the current file `vboxapisetup.py` and replace **line 57**, from `vboxDest = os.environ.get("VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH", None)` to `vboxDest = "/usr/lib/virtualbox"`

Then run agin:

```
sudo python3 vboxapisetup.py install
```

And now you will get something like that:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
copying vboxapi/__init__.py -> build/lib/vboxapi
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi
copying build/lib/vboxapi/__init__.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi
copying build/lib/vboxapi/VirtualBox_constants.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi/VirtualBox_constants.py to VirtualBox_constants.cpython-36.pyc
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi-1.0.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi-1.0.egg-info
```

which mean that **we are ok** with `vboxapi` package installation !

---

Now, let's try again to load virtualbox() inside python3:

```
from virtualbox import VirtualBox, Session, Manager, WebServiceManager
box = VirtualBox()
```

this probably will raise this new issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "virtualbox_python3_test.py", line XX, in <module>
    vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualbox/library_ext/vbox.py", line 22, in __init__
    manager = virtualbox.Manager()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualbox/__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.manager = vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager(mtype, mparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 989, in __init__
    self.platform = PlatformXPCOM(dPlatformParams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 750, in __init__
    import xpcom.vboxxpcom
  File "/usr/lib/virtualbox/sdk/bindings/xpcom/python/xpcom/vboxxpcom.py", line 78, in <module>
    raise Exception('Cannot find VBoxPython module (tried: %s)' % (', '.join(_asVBoxPythons),))
Exception: Cannot find VBoxPython module (tried: VBoxPython3_6m, VBoxPython3m, VBoxPython)
```

If you dig you will find a lot of questions ([question 1](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=83805),[question 2](https://github.com/sethmlarson/virtualbox-python/issues/116),[question 3](https://github.com/sethmlarson/virtualbox-python/issues/102), [question 4](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=88166) etc...) relative to this issue on the web ...

But according to my dig & research, if you are lucky (and have a Virtualbox built with python3 native support) you can try:

```
cd /usr/lib/virtualbox/
sudo cp VBoxPython3_5m.so VBoxPython3_6m.so
```

But if you got the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat 'VBoxPython3_5m.so': No such file or directory
```

It mean that you don't have native python3 support in Virtualbox...

This could be solved like this:

Go [here](https://opensuse.pkgs.org/15.0/opensuse-update-oss/python3-virtualbox-5.2.16-lp150.4.11.1.x86_64.rpm.html) and download [the python3-virtualbox-5.2.16 binary package](http://widehat.opensuse.org/opensuse/update/leap/15.0/oss/x86_64/python3-virtualbox-5.2.16-lp150.4.11.1.x86_64.rpm) (we don't care about the VirtualBox version...)

Now open `python3-virtualbox-5.2.16-lp150.4.11.1.x86_64.rpm` archive, browse it  to `/./usr/lib/virtualbox/`, then extract the file `VBoxPython3_6m.so`, then drop this file in your current working directory, after that from this directory you have to do:

```
sudo cp VBoxPython3_6m.so /usr/lib/virtualbox/
```

And now, **you can use python3 binding for virtualbox** !

Comment: please note that some 'virtualbox' module function will not work properly due principally to the difference between python2 and python3 (for e.g string representation, take a look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088041/virtualbox-api-take-screen-shot-to-array-function-raise-an-unicode-error-only)

Comment: A do agree with A STEFANI. Moreover, it is better to export or simple set needed envvars instead of editing sources: `sudo VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/lib/virtualbox python3 vboxapisetup.py install` - worked for me