# How can I set up a VirtualBox interface using a Python library in 2022?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualbox

I have a local installation of VirtualBox running on my host machine, which is running Windows 10. I am able to start and run a virtual machine of Ubuntu via the VirtualBox GUI application.

I need to be able to manage the state of that virtual machine using python. As far as I know, the only routes for me to pursue this are:

- [`virtualbox-python`](https://github.com/sethmlarson/virtualbox-python) library on Github (last active 2020, build failing)
- [`vboxapi`](https://pypi.org/project/vboxapi/) library on PyPi (last active 2012, build failing)
- [`virtual-machines-python-manage`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage), which I have not attempted to use since it requires Azure services (which eventually require a [paid subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/))

Using this [very similar post from June 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44477318/is-it-possible-to-use-the-python3-bindings-for-virtualbox), which was answered by the `vboxapi` maintainer/`virtualbox-python` repo hoster at that time, I've surmised that the process should be to easily import the `virtualbox` or `vboxapi` libraries.

However, when I run a function of either library, I receive the error `No module named 'vboxapi`'.

To fix this, I should be able to:

1. Go to VirtualBox's downloads page (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and download the VirtualBox SDK.
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Navigate into the subdirectory 'sdk\installer'
4. Open command prompt in this subdirectory using Administrator mode.
5. Run `python vboxapisetup.py install`.

This should install `vboxapi`, but instead I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\PATH_HERE\VirtualBoxSDK-6.1.30-148432\sdk\installer>python vboxapisetup.py install
Cleaning COM cache at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py and C:\Users\USER_HERE\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py
running install
running build
running build_py
copying vboxapi\__init__.py -> build\lib\vboxapi
running install_lib
creating C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\vboxapi
error: could not create 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\vboxapi': Access is denied
```

Is this a Path error? Am I overlooking something simple in environmental variables?

[This post for the same problem on a ubuntu host machine](http://www.cesareriva.com/how-to-install-the-virtualbox-sdk/) suggests running the following commands:

```
export VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=$(which VirtualBox)
sudo -E python vboxapisetup.py install
```

Is there a windows equivalent method I can try here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was never able to directly run any sort of VirtualBox management software from within python: none of the libraries listed worked for me.

Instead, what I ended up doing was execute bash shell scripts that called VBoxManage and each subsequent command needed. I then had to pipe the results (text output to the terminal from VBoxManage) back into Python and parse the text.

Answer (score 0):

Some support may be found in other corners of Internet, for example at
https://kodekloud.com/community/t/missing-dependencies-python-core-win32api/215281/27

In short - install Python for Windows from the Python website ([Download Python | Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)) then run one of commands:

`pip install pywin32`

or:

`py -m pip install pywin32`

Please note that you may also need to reinstall VirtualBox for the changes to take effect.